# check how many of the last 50 bars closed above moving average

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am wondering if there is a better way to check how many of the last 50 bars closed above or below a moving average

The only solution i can come up with is by checking it bar by bar like:

```
bar1 = close[1] > MA1[1] ? 1 : -1
bar2 = close[2] > MA1[2] ? 1 : -1
```

etc.

then after this i would need to see what % closed above and below like:

```
count = bar1 + bar2 + bar3 + bar4 ..... + bar 50

percentage = count / 50 * 100
```

Is there a function or a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to use this is to use `math.sum()`.

> The sum function returns the sliding sum of last y values of x.

So, you need to pass your condition with `length` being `50` and it will check your condition within the last 50 bars and return you the sliding sum.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

sma_9 = ta.sma(close, 9)
condition = (close > sma_9)

cnt = math.sum(condition ? 1 : 0, 50)

plot(sma_9)
plotchar(cnt, "cnt", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also throw it through a loop and create a function to calculate the percent:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

len = input(50, "Lookback Length") 

sma_9 = ta.sma(close, 9)
bool above = close > sma_9 
bool below = close < sma_9

f_perc(count) => 
    (count / len) * 100 
    
int a_c = 0 
int b_c = 0 

for i = 0 to len
    if above[i]
        a_c +=1
    if below[i]
        b_c += 1 

above_perc = f_perc(a_c) 
below_perc = f_perc(b_c) 

plot(math.round(above_perc, 2), "Above Percent", color=color.lime)
plot(math.round(below_perc, 2), "Below Percent", color=color.red)
```

This allows you to adjust the length of the loockback as well, if you don't want it to count longer or shorter than 50 candles back.

The quickest way is to use the way the other person showed you, you can just take the percent function and add it to his/her code as such:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

sma_9 = ta.sma(close, 9)
condition = (close > sma_9)

cnt = math.sum(condition ? 1 : 0, 50)


f_perc(count) => 
    (count / 50) * 100 

above_perc = f_perc(cnt) 

plot(math.round(above_perc,2))
```